# Reduce cassandra tombstones

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0, tombstone

I have a table to store messages which are failed to process and I am retrying to process messages every 5 minutes through scheduler.

When message gets processed successfully, respective row from table is deleted, so that same message should not get processed again.

To fetch rows from table query is `SELECT * FROM <table_name>` , due to which we are facing tombstone issues if large number of rows gets deleted.
Table have timestamp as partition key and message_name(TEXT) as clustering key, TTL of 7 days and gc_grace_second of 2 days

As per my requirement, I need to delete records otherwise duplicate record will get processed. Is there any solution to avoid tombstone issues?

Answer (score 2):

So I see two problems here.

1. Cassandra is being used as a queuing mechanism, which is an established anti-pattern.
2. All partitions are being queried with `SELECT * FROM <table_name>`, because there isn't a `WHERE` clause.

So with Cassandra, some data models and use cases *will* generate tombstones.  At that point, there's not a whole lot to be done, except to design the data model so as to *not query them*.

So my thought here, would be to partition the table differently.

```
CREATE TABLE messages (
    day TEXT,
    message_time TIMESTAMP,
    message_text TEXT,
    PRIMARY KEY ((day),message_time))
WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (message_time DESC);
```

With this model, you can query all messages for a particular `day`.  You can also run a range query on `day` and `message_time`.  Ex:

```
SELECT * FROM messages
WHERE day='20210827'
AND message_time > '2021-08-27 04:00';
```

This will build a result set of all messages since `2021-08-27 04:00`.  Any tombstones generated outside of the requested time range (in this case, before 04:00) will not be queried.

Note that (based on the delete pattern) you could still have tombstones *within* the given time range.  But the idea here, is that the `WHERE` clause limits the "blast radius," so querying a smaller number of tombstones shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: I am afraid that I cannot use greater than specific time in WHERE clause. I am processing data from table which is older than 5 minutes than current time. Currently I am handling the logic in my code. But with new table structure, as per your suggestion I need to do query with WHERE clause as 
`SELECT * FROM messages
WHERE day='20210827'
AND message_time < current_timestamp - 5 minutes`
But I see this will scan most of the records for the day as we move forward with time for the day.

Comment: @CKP Even if you took the `message_time` filter off of the `WHERE` clause, you would still only scan messages for a single day, and not from multiple partitions (like your original query indicates).  Regardless of the specifics in my answer, the main goal here is to make adjustments so that you're not querying too many tombstones.  Work on that, and you should see some improvement.

Comment: Yes Aaron, I agree. Just want to see if there is any improvement can be done with WHERE clause so that we can scan less tombstones. Also, I am planning to reduce gc_grace_seconds to 1 day. Do you see any issues with it?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there isn't a quick fix to your problem.

The challenge for you is that you're using Cassandra as a queue and it isn't a good idea because you run exactly into that tombstone hell. I'm sure you've seen [this blog post](https://www.datastax.com/blog/cassandra-anti-patterns-queues-and-queue-datasets) by now that talks queues and queue-like datasets being an anti-pattern for Cassandra.

It is possible to avoid generating lots of tombstones if you model your data differently in buckets with each bucket mapping to a table. When you're done processing all the items in the bucket, `TRUNCATE` the table. This idea came from Ryan Svihla in his blog post [Understanding Deletes](https://foundev.medium.com/domain-modeling-around-deletes-1cc9b6da0d24) where he goes through the idea of "partitioning tables". Cheers!

Comment: I have thought similar kind of approach previously, but I see we are adding more complexity at code level. Also, we don't want to truncate the table on production because if any issue occurs while processing data from table, it may cause data loss. Obviously there are various approach we can handle it, but again we will add complexity in code and more database calls means it will be more error prone.

Comment: The complexity comes from the fact that your use case is anti-pattern for Cassandra so you need to make the necessary adaptations to make it work. Cheers!